# Break loop for every 5th loop

Tags: jquery, css, json, loops, for-loop

I'd like to add a simple bit of code to my HTML (the list item) for every 5th loop.

Here is my code:

```
 if (jsonData != null && jsonData.length > 0){
     for (i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
         if( jsonData[i].name.length > 15 ) 
                 cname = jsonData[i].name.substr(0,15);
         else cname = jsonData[i].name ;
         resHTML += '<li><a title="'+ jsonData[i].name +'" href="'+ jsonData[i].link +'"><img width="137" height="175" alt="'+ jsonData[i].name +'" src="'+ jsonData[i].img +'"></a><br><a href="'+ jsonData[i].link +'">'+ cname +'</a></li>' ;

     }
 }
```

So for every 5th loop, the `<li>` would become `<li style="margin-right:0">`

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Use modulus 5 checking against 0 and then add your custom logic.

Comment: `if(i % 5 == 0)` // Execute alt. code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to handle this with JavaScript.

Use this simple CSS:

```
li + li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

That will apply `margin-left` to all except the first `li`, which should be the same as applying `margin-right` to all but the last `li`.

`+` is the [adjacent sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

Comment: WOW!!! So simple and it worked beautifully. So much I still don't know about CSS :) Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
if ((i % 5) == 0)
  // add your margin stuff
```

Basically, the modulus (the remainder of i divided by 5) will be 0 every 5 iteration

Comment: Cool. So it would be `if ((i % 5) == 0) resHTML += '<li style="margin-right:0">' else resHTML += '<li>' }` ?

Comment: Yes... (i have to add some chars for the comment to insert)

Comment: Thanks for the edit (to add the code tags) Our modifications overwritten each other, but I re-added it

Comment: Thank you, Mike. thirtydot posted an uber simple CSS fix which has done the trick too.

Answer (score 1):

one possibility would be to test if `i % 5 == 0` this will evaluate to true every 5 iterations of the loop.

code:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(!(i % 5))
    {
        //every fifth iteration!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would.. set `for(i = 1; i <= jsonData.length; i++)`

Then do:

`if((i % 5) == 0) { // margin code }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if((i%5)==0)
   resHTML += "<li style=\"margin-right:0\">"
else
   restHTML += "<li>"
restHTML += "<add all other stuff after li >"
```